# Run a Flask app forever, even after reboot

Tags: python, linux, flask

I have a running Flask app that is working fine on a Linux (CentOS) server.
To make it work in the background I started it within a `screen` session. There is scheduled downtime for the server every night. The next day all screen sessions are gone. How can I keep my Flask app or screen sessions always up and running after reboots?

Comment: Write a simple `systemd` service. Check [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-a-flask-application-as-a-service-with-systemd)

Comment: "There is a scheduled downtime of a server every night". SRLY? you should have chat with the admin about this.

Comment: Why should have a chat with admin? It is a policy for most of departments to shut down at night and spin up in the morning since is 100% internally used applications on servers and 95% of people do not need to work on them from e.g. midnight to 6am.

Comment: @hansolo THANK YOU! The `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` command, discussed in the article you posted, was what I was missing. I spent hours making changes to my service and program but nothing was taking effect because I didn't run that command.

Comment: @Smitty-Werben-Jager-Manjenson Glad i could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Han Solo gave a good answer in his comment: if you run it as a `systemd` service, it'll run on boot, restart if it crashes, and so on.

However, if you just need a quick-and-dirty solution for a couple days while you configure the service properly, you can use `cron`:

- Run `crontab -e` to edit your crontab file
- Add a line at the bottom that looks like this:

  ```
  @reboot [put your command here]
  ```
- Save and exit the editor
- `sudo reboot` to test it and make sure it works

And you're done! The command will now run whenever the system reboots.